# change add string on key dictionaries which contain string on variables

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem which need to be solved, but i dont know what an idea to solve this.

i have a dictionary here and variables that contains string, and i want to add up a variables string in my dictionaries keys. Here my example :

here is my variables that i want to add up on keys in dictionaries.
test = '2019'

and here is my old dictionary

```
dict = {'X':12, 'Y':13}
```

my wish dictionary are add up about old+string on variables

```
wishdict = {'X2019':12. 'Y2019':13}
```

Comment: take a look at comprehension list (or dictionnary in that case). something like `{'{}{}'.format(k, test):v for k, v in dict.items()}` should do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dictionary comprehension with `f-string`s:

```
test = '2019'
d = {'X':12, 'Y':13}
wishdict = {f'{k}{test}': v for k, v in d.items()}
print (wishdict)
{'X2019': 12, 'Y2019': 13}
```